# How to set instance field to final in Stateless widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have `Stateless` widget. When user tap button I call method which calculate value. I need pass this value to next page with `Navigator.push`.

For example, I have:

```
class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  String value1;
  String value2;

…

child: RaisedButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    await _calculateValue(context);

    Navigator.push(
        context,
        new MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                new Page2(
                  value1: value1,
                  value2: value2,
                )));

…

_calculateValue(BuildContext context) async {

value1 = …
value2 = …
```

But when I do this `flutter analyze` give warning:

> This class (or a class which this class inherits from) is marked as
>   '@immutable', but one or more of its instance fields are not final

I cannot just declare `value1` final because it then give error:

> error: The final variable ‘value1’ must be initialized.

How I can solve this?

Comment: by using `StatefulWidget`?

Comment: @pskink Thanks for reply! I was think maybe there is better way I can return value from `_calculateValue` method?

Comment: this is from the official documentation: *"Stateful widgets are useful when the part of the user interface you are describing can change dynamically, e.g. due to having an internal clock-driven state, or depending on some system state. For compositions that depend only on the configuration information in the object itself and the BuildContext in which the widget is inflated, consider using StatelessWidget."*

Comment: @pskink Thanks! But I am not update anything in UI with `value1`. I only calculate so I can send to next page

Comment: so do not use `String value1;
  String value2;` as the fields, instead define them inside `onPressed` function body

Comment: @pskink I am try but cannot find how? I can return field from function?

Comment: `onPressed: () async { var String value1; var String value2; ...`

Comment: @pskink Thanks! So I pass into `_calculateValue`. But how I can get value back out?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are trying to get or calculate some values and then pass them as parameters from one screen to another. You can accomplish this by using named routes with special class. You can retrieve values on the second screen with `ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments`. For your situation it can be something like that:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScreenArguments {
  final String value1;
  final String value2;

  ScreenArguments(this.value1, this.value2);
}

class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/';
  String getSomeValue() {
    return "value";
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // Consider using loader if getting values takes too much time
          var value1 = getSomeValue();
          var value2 = getSomeValue();

          Navigator.pushNamed(
            context,
            SecondScreen.routeName,
            arguments: ScreenArguments(value1, value2),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/secondScreen';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ScreenArguments args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

    var value1 = args.value1;
    var value2 = args.value2;

    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[Text(value1), Text(value2)],
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(initialRoute: FirstScreen.routeName, routes: {
      FirstScreen.routeName: (context) => FirstScreen(),
      SecondScreen.routeName: (context) => SecondScreen(),
    });
  }
}
```

More detailed about named routes you can read [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes) and [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments).

Comment: Thanks for reply! You example is good but have one issue. I must calculate `value1` and `value2` in same function. But in dart cannot return 2 value. So how I can do?

Comment: @FlutterFirebase Inside onPressed you can just define string value 1; string value2 and then assign its values by calling  _calculateValue() method. Also you can try wrap both variables with the simple class, define according variable in onPressed and assign its value by _calculateValue().